# Add more values to xml element

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml that looks like this. I'm been stuck for a while on trying to add more values to the Author element.

I load it in like so:

```
XDocument cdata = XDocument.Parse(text);
```

here is the sample xml:

```
<a xmlns="http://www" version="5.050">  
  <Books>
   <Author> Poe,Edgar Allen Homer Walden</Author>
   <Address></Address>
   <State></State>
 </Books>
 <SYSTEM type="OTHER">
   <ORGANIZATION id="" />
 </SYSTEM>
 <HMDA_INFO is_hoepa="N" is_hoepa_manual="N" />
</a>
```

Just a side note 'a' is not necessarily always the root element name sometimes its b or c so I can't go by the root name.

Tried doing this to access Author but I get sequence contains no elements:

```
XDocument cdata = XDocument.Parse(text);
var addElement = cdata.Descendants("Books").First();
addElement.SetAttributeValue("Authors", "insert this.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. First is that `Author` is an element, not attribute. And second - you forgot about namespace declared in `a` element:

```
XDocument cdata = XDocument.Parse(text);
XNamespace ns = "http://www";
var books = cdata.Descendants(ns + "Books").First();
var author = books.Element(ns + "Author"); 
author.Value = "insert this." + authors.Value;
```

Or if you want just to add new attribute to authors element:

```
books.Element(ns + "Author").SetAttributeValue(ns + "Foo", "insert this.");
```

Comment: I would like to add more values inside the element Author so before 'Poe,Edgar Allen' but keep the existing values as well.

Comment: Author node is a part of the main XML. If you see value in author node, then its in cdata document. Want to save it? Call `cdata.Save(fileName)`.

Comment: Do you know off hand if there is a way to remove a portion of xml at a specific point, edit it, then append it back on at that position?

Comment: @ERead sure, there are number of helpful methods like [ReplaceWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx) for replacing node content, or [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) to remove nodes from xml.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will access Author node

```
var addElement = cdata.Descendants("Books").First();
var authodNode = addElement.Element("Author")
```

below you can find a test I have done

[image]

Comment: I get an error at runtime saying sequence contains no elements